# android.app.Application cannot be cast to MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I get this error when I'm trying to start an intent from my wear to my mobile. When I press a button on my watch there's a message send to the listenerservice. And I'm trying to start a method from my listenerService to my `MainActivity` but I'm getting the error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.my_emergency.samdesmedt.my_emergency.MainActivity
>   at com.my_emergency.samdesmedt.my_emergency.ListenerServiceFromWear.onMessageReceived(ListenerServiceFromWear.java:28)

This is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my_emergency.samdesmedt.my_emergency">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AddActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EditSettingsActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EditActivity" >
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".ListenerServiceFromWear">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my ListenerServiceFromWear.Java

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
    super.onMessageReceived(messageEvent);

    if (messageEvent.getPath().equals(WEARPATH)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("isEmergency", true);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

This is the code in my mainActivity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
boolean isEmergency = intent.getBooleanExtra("isEmergency", false);

if(isEmergency){
    startEmergencyMode(message);
}
```

Comment: I am just trying my chance..
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class); or
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

Comment: this fixed it thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
```

fixed it